# Menu options for applications are all inactive

Tags: unity, globalmenu

I recently upgraded to 13.10 and in trying to get some things worked out (e.g. wireless), I screwed up something and now the global menu options for all my applications are grayed out, e.g. I can't select 'Paste' in the terminal menu even if I have some text in my clipboard.

Is there a fix for this? I'm really stuck.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the system?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.
I temporary fixed it by some applications to add:

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=1
```

to the start up file.